# iterator contains reference to list in python

Tags: python, iterator

Does iterator contains reference to list in python? If yes, then why I get different memory addresses for my list and iterator object? I am beginner, please help me. I am so confused.

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(id(l))
it=iter(l)
print(id(it))

Output
2945903217024
2945901788032
```

The list iterator has the reference to the list and the current index in the list. It does not have its own copy of the list. Please also elaborate this statement.

Comment: If iterator is a different object, then how it can access values from an iterable? How it connects to the values of an iterable?

Comment: iter makes a copy of your passed iterable

Comment: I don't think so because if iterator makes  a copy of your passed iterable, then how an iterator would be memory efficient? ( As it loads the elements one by one from an iterable using next() method).

Answer (score 2):

> why I get different memory addresses for my list and iterator object?

`id(it)` is the ID of the *iterator*, which is its own object, with its own ID. The ID of what it's iterating over doesn't matter.

```
In [42]: iter([])
Out[42]: <list_iterator at 0x7f84a5570880>

In [43]: iter([])
Out[43]: <list_iterator at 0x7f84a943cf70>
```

What `iter` returned here is a `list_iterator` object, not the list itself. Maybe `list_iterator` contains a reference to the list, but it doesn't mean that the iterator object *is* the list, which equal IDs would imply.

---

I think the iterator contains a reference to the list:

1. I assume that `iter(some_list)` calls [`list_iter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5a97a93be086c19343df4352672bfda32f6cbd0c/Objects/listobject.c#L3183):

   ```
   static PyObject * list_iter(PyObject *seq)
   ```

   Here `seq` should be the list.
2. Within `list_iter` the iterator object is created: `_PyListIterObject *it;`
3. During initialization of `it`, the pointer to the original list is assigned to `it`'s `it_seq` field:

   ```
   it->it_seq = (PyListObject *)seq;
   ```
4. From the definition of [`_PyListIterObject`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ef73be891eb95064e268341e38e81d008add480/Include/internal/pycore_list.h#L72-L76) one could deduce that the `it_seq` field is indeed the "reference" ("pointer" in C terminology) to the object that the list iterator iterates over:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       PyObject_HEAD
       Py_ssize_t it_index;
       PyListObject *it_seq; /* Set to NULL when iterator is exhausted */
   } _PyListIterObject;
   ```

So yes, I think `_PyListIterObject::it_seq` is the reference to the list that the iterator iterates over.

Comment: Does iterator contains reference to list in python or not?

Comment: Why did you execute that code twice? I don't see what that's intended to show.

Comment: @ForceBru you said maybe an iterator have reference to list, can you please explain how an iterator access the values from an iterable?

Comment: @AliHaider I don't understand your problem. If you write code you can loop over an iterable (with e.g. a `for` loop). Now you create an iterator for this iterable. Why shouldn't the iterator be able to use the same logic to loop over the iterable?

Comment: @AliHaider, if I understand CPython's code correctly, the iterator does have a reference to the list. Otherwise it wouldn't know where to obtain the values that it's supposed to yield.

Comment: @ForceBru Of course it has. Why else would we provide the iterable as a parameter of `iter`?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I'm not really sure why I executed it twice. Maybe it was meant to show that you get different `list_iterator` objects, but there's no particular deep reason here, I think

Comment: @Matthias I actually want to know that how iterators access values from iterables. Does iterators have reference to iterable objects?

Comment: @AliHaider Yes. When you do `it = iter(l)` you create an iterator `it` that has a reference to `l`.

Comment: @Matthias if iterator holds a reference to list, then why the python interpreter prints the id values of list and iterator different?

Comment: @AliHaider, the list and the iterator are different objects. Different objects have different `id`s. That the iterator has a reference to the list doesn't matter because the iterator is not _literally that list_. It's a different object, so it has a different ID.

Comment: Have you ever worked with classes? Then imagine the iterable as an attribute of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that the "id" shown is not of the data itself, but of the object.

Since they are two different objects it is normal for them to have different "ids".